# Convert point coordinates to a new coordinate system

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Let's say I have point which has the coordinates (50,100) where (0,0) is in the upper left corner of a view.

How can I get the coordinates of the same point if I want the beginning of the coordinate system to be the center of the screen (ie width/2, height/2) ?

Note that I am implementing a custom View and I am drawing inside it and I just want to convert the coordinate inside that same view. I am basically implementing a graphic calculator and I need to have my coordinate system to start in the middle of the screen so the graphics could look better.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Find the midpoint you will be using, so for a 100x100 screen, this would be (50,50). Then take the point you need to convert and subtract the midpoint X value from the point X value, and then subtract the point Y value from the midpoint Y value. Notice that you are not doing the same operation on both values.

So if the point is (30,25) the new point would be (-20,25) because 30 - 50 = -20 and 50 - 25 = 25.

Answer (score 3):

I notice you tagged it as iOS problem, so use the method Apple have built in UIView:

`(CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view`